# How to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ where $f(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2}(1+\frac{1}{2t})^t\sin{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}dt(x>0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> $$f(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2t}\right)^t\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)dt\hspace{1cm}(x>0)$$
>   try to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

I found this problem from a problem book and with a hint which tells me to apply L'Hospital's rule. 
But when $n\to\infty$ then $\frac{1}{\sin(1/n)}\to\infty$ and $f(n)\text{ seems}\to0$.
Would you help me with this problem? Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to find the derivative $f'(x) $ and it is evaluated using a combination of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and Chain rule as $$f'(x) =\left(1+\frac{1}{2x^{2}}\right)^{x^{2}}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot 2x - \left(1+\frac{1}{2x}\right)^{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$ and thus $f'(x) \to e^{1/2}\cdot 2-e^{1/2}\cdot 0=2\sqrt{e}$ as $x\to\infty$. It follows by L'Hospital's Rule that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)} {x} =2\sqrt{e}$$ and therefore $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=2\sqrt{e}$$ It follows that if $n$ is a positive integer then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=2\sqrt{e}$$

---

In the above we have used two standard limits $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{t}{x}\right)^{x}=e^{t},\, \lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me why $f(x)\to\infty$ when $x\to\infty$? The formula in the integral $\to{e^{\frac{1}{2}}\sin{0}}=0$. The width is tends to infinity too. It looks like a $0\cdot\infty$

Comment: @Alfred: Why do you need $f(x) \to \infty$? Remember L'Hospital's Rule applies to $0/0$ and $\text {anything} /\infty$. Thus one needs to check that denominator tends to infinity and not worry about numerator at all. This fact about L'Hospital's Rule is not emphasized very well in books so many are not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\int^{x^2}_x (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt$$
$$f(n)=\int^{n^2}_n (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)\sin{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin{\frac{1}{n}}\int^{n^2}_n (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin{\frac{1}{n}}\int^{n^2}_n (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin{\frac{1}{n}}\int^{n^2}_0 (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt-\sin{\frac{1}{n}}\int^{n}_0 (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\int^{n^2}_0 (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt-\int^{n}_0 (1+\frac{1}{2t})^t \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}})dt}{\csc(\frac{1}{n})}$$
First show that this is in indeterminant form, then differentiate the top and bottom with L'Hopital.  You can do so with the Fundamental Theorem of calculus.

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})\frac{2n(1+\frac{1}{2n^2})^{n^2} \sin(\frac{1}{n})-(1+\frac{1}{2n})^n \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})}{\cos(\frac{1}{n})}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})\biggl(2n(1+\frac{1}{2n^2})^{n^2} \sin(\frac{1}{n})-(1+\frac{1}{2n})^n \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\biggr)$$

Answer (score 0):

First prove that $f(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ then apply L'Hopital rule
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f'(n)}{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)'}$$

$$f'(n)=2 \left(\frac{1}{2 n^2}+1\right)^{n^2} n \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2 n}+1\right)^n \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

and
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)'=\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^2 \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\right)}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2 \left(\frac{1}{2 n^2}+1\right)^{n^2} n \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2 n}+1\right)^n \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\frac{2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n^2 \left(\cos \left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\right)}}=$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[n^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \left(2 \left(\frac{1}{2 n^2}+1\right)^{n^2} n \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2 n}+1\right)^n \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right) \tan \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]$$

Now recalling that $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t=e;\;\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1;\;\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\tan z}{z}=1$$

you should arrive to the result $2 \sqrt{e}$